# setLoginUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, mern

I am making a login application when i am clicking the login button the i am reciving an error (loginPage.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setLoginUser is not a function)
here is the code of app.js

```
function App() {
  const [user,setLoginUser] = useState({})
return(
  <div className='App'>
<BrowserRouter>
  < Routes>
    <Route path="/homepage" element={user && user?._id? <Homepage /> : <Login setLoginUser={setLoginUser} />}/>
   
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} setLoginUser={setLoginUser}/>
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
   
  </div>
)
}
```

and here is the code of loginPage.js where error is occuring

```
const Login = ({ setLoginUser }) => {
   const login = () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:4000/login", user)
    .then(res => {
      alert(res.data.message)
      console.log(res.data.user)
      setLoginUser(res.data.user)
     navigate('/homepage')
   })
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, show a full code of loginPage

Comment: Props for `Login` need to go on `Login` and not on `Route`

Comment: @Yoskutik kindly check this image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass your `setLoginUser` function to `Login` component in your routes.

```js
<Route path="/login" element={<Login setLoginUser={setLoginUser} />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace :

`<Route path="/login" element={<Login />} setLoginUser={setLoginUser}/>`

by

`<Route path="/login" element={<Login setLoginUser={setLoginUser}/>} />`

I don't think it's a good idea to path variable like that in the root element but this should works.

Why do you have `<BrowserRouter>` and `<Routes>` ?